# iOS slight shift of elements appearing in page item controller

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm encountering a little problem using a UIPageViewController (a 3 pages walkthrough) :

When I slide to change the current page, when the new page is just displaying, images and texts on it are maybe 50 pixels on the top of their normal position during an half second, and after they recover their normal places.

The shift is pretty little, but it's visible when users are trying it. I tried to remove all constraints but there is always the same problem.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: are you setting the constraints in viewDidAppear?

Comment: I just set this : `self.walkthrough.numberOfLines = 0;
                        self.walkthrough.sizeToFit()`
and that's all. (for my text displayed on multiple lines) I already tried to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem : it was the status bar of the device (with the battery icon etc...) which was pushing down elements. So you just have to hide it.